# How to get field type from $form_state?

Tags: 8, forms

How do i get field type (e.g *textfield*, *option*, etc.) from `$form_state` in below method.

```php
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
```

Comment: Can you not get it from `$form`? It's available right there.

Comment: See $form_state['fields'] or something like that.

Comment: When you write 'field type' do you mean the entity field type? Or a render element type?

Comment: @Eyal render element type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before, it is in

```
$form['fieldname']['#type']
```

You don't need the state for this because it is not a state, it's static.

Answer (score 0):

no filed type in $form_state

you can use $form instead

Answer (score 0):

The render element types are defined using the #type property in the render array.

The only render element that the form state object (*might [1]*) reference directly is the main form element, via the **getCompleteForm** method.

[1] the form builder object sets the complete form parameter on the form state while building the form, so I'm the early stages it might not yet be set.

P.S.

The form state object does hold a reference the form object. Which
means that in entity forms, you can get the entity and it's fields
from the form state object.